# Why when i copy file from a symlink directory one level up copy is created one level up from original directory?

Tags: cp, ln

```
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~$  mkdir -p ~/foo/bar/
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~$ touch ~/foo/bar/test.txt
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~$  mkdir ~/baz/
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~$ ln -s ~/foo/bar/ ~/baz/bar
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~$ cd ~/baz/bar/
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~/baz/bar$ cp test.txt ../
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~/baz/bar$ cd ..
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~/baz$ ls
bar
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~/baz$ cd ~/foo
user@DESKTOP-KK4CCE2:~/foo$ ls
bar  test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The gotcha is that when you `cd ~/baz/bar` you are now actually in `~/foo/bar`. Your path only *appears* to be where you expect. So `..` is the parent directory of `~/foo/bar`, which is actually `~/foo`.

Comment: Accessing the source through the link while in `~/baz`, or giving the full path of the target from `~/baz/bar` would have worked: `cd ~/baz && cp bar/test.txt .` or `cd ~/baz/bar && cp test.txt ~/baz`